# Cant access htaccess protected php script from android application

Tags: java, php, android, .htaccess, url

I am running a webserver where i put a .php file to access a mysql database. now that i dont want this .php file to be viewed public i put .htaccess on the containing folder.

now i that i want to pass the account name and password in the URL it doesnt get to work.

```
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://accname:password@server.com/admin/myfile.php");
```

but when i call the url out of a browser it does work. i am pretty lost - is there something i am doing wrong ?

Comment: What exception do you get?

Comment: a JSONException but only because there are no results returned from database i guess

Comment: Does it say why you can't access the page you're trying to load?

Comment: no it doesnt say anything

Comment: Why not just put the file outside of the public html folder (or htdocs, etc) and call it that way.